# Possible to use one RegEx group for multiple matches?

Tags: regex

Example Text:

```
[ABC[[value='123'SomeTextHere[]]][value='5463',SomedifferentTextwithdifferentlength]][[value='Text';]]]]][ABC [...]
```

Current RegEx:

```
[ABC.*?(?:value='(.*?)')+.*?]]]
```

What I want to achive:

There's an extremely long text (HTTP Response) with data I want to grab. A single dataset contains multiple lines. On every line the data I want to collect is located inside the "value:''" tag. On each line there are multiple of those value tags. Is it somehow possible to use (optimize) the above regex to get the data of all value tags with just a single capturing group in the regex pattern?

To clarify what I want: alternatively I would have to use the following pattern:

```
[ABC.*?value='(.*?)'.*?value='(.*?)'.*?value='(.*?)'.*?value='(.*?)'.*?]]]
```

Comment: Why not just capture all `value='()'`s, or do some texts lack ABC which you want to exclude?

Comment: Please tag your question with a language or a tool.

Comment: @CertainPerformance when just looking for the value part, I'm not able to separate them into data sets.

Comment: IIRC with .net regex, you can get repeated capture groups like you're looking for, but otherwise you'll have to either repeat the `value` groups manually many times like you suggested, or you'll use a programmatic solution outside of regex alone.

Answer (score 0):

Using Perl, you can easily get at all matches of a regular expression, and most of the other regular expression libraries have similar capabilities. As you want to match a header, doing a repeated match with an anchor ( `\G` )is the easiest:

```
use strict;
#use Regexp::Debugger;
my $data = "[ABC[[value='123'SomeTextHere[]]][value='5463',SomedifferentTextwithdifferentlength]][[value='Text';]]]]][ABC [...]";
my @matches = $data =~ /(?:^\[ABC|\G).*?\bvalue='([^']*)'/g;
print "[$_]" for @matches;

__END__
[123][5463][Text]
```

Most likely you will need to add the "global" flag to whatever regex library you are using for matching.

Personally, I would split this up into a two-step process. First, extract the string between `[ABC[[` and `]]]`, and then extract all `value='...'` parts from that string. Also, most likely, you can parse the string `[ABC[[...]]]` in a sane way, counting opening and closing brackets. Or maybe that string is even JSON and you can just use a proper parser there?